# iOS Provisioning membership is renewed, what next?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-provisioning

After my iOS membership is expired, certificate and all provisions are gets revoked. After few days I renewed my provisioning membership. Now I need to give request for development certificate, So my question is How is it going to affect my existing apps and existing provisioning profiles? Can I give request for development certificate from other machine?
Please help.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revoking certificates has no effect on existing apps (AppStore/AdHoc/Dev).

Regenerate your provisioning profiles (make sure your new certificate is checked in the certificate list). Then you'll just have to code sign your updates with the new provisioning profile.

You can set up the new certificate on another machine if you want.

Comment: Thank You Jilouc, I am going to try it.